# How to make a Yahoo 10 IM Auto Reply program in C++?

Tags: c++, instant-messaging, yahoo-messenger

How to make a Yahoo Auto Reply program in C++?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you might want to look into is the Yahoo Messenger SDK http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/